# chroot SFTP- works only on user directory but not on other directories

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, ssh, staging, chroot

on Ubuntu 20.04
I have a WordPress site on directory /var/www/site.com/public_html/
I created a staging site inside the mail directory /var/www/site.com/public_html/stagesite

I am trying to five access only to the stagesite folder to be accessed by developer to be able to edit and update files inside.

Steps taken

1. created user "developer" and group "restricted" and developer user is a restricted group user
2. updated the folder owner and permissions sudo chown -R root:root stagesite/ && sudo chmod -R 775 /stagesite
3. added to the end of sshd_config file /etc/ssh/sshd_config

> ```
> Match Group restricted
>   # Force the connection to use SFTP and chroot to the required directory.
>   ForceCommand internal-sftp
>   ChrootDirectory /var/www/mainsite.com/public_html/stagesite
>   # Disable tunneling, authentication agent, TCP and X11 forwarding.
>   PermitTunnel no
>   AllowAgentForwarding no
>   AllowTcpForwarding no
>   X11Forwarding no
> ```

NOW tried to connect with Filezilla, it will not connect using SFTP
I tried adding sub-directory to the ChrootDirectory to be like below but still didn't connect
/var/www/mainsite.com/public_html/stagesite/wp-content

I was only able to connect when setting ChrootDirectory to the user home directory
/home/developer

Answer (score 0):

It is required that all directories from the home of the chrooted user to the root must be owned by root:root and must not be group or world writable. This is probably not the case for fileadmin home directory.

Comment: updated the folder owner and permissions sudo chown -R root:root stagesite/ && sudo chmod -R 775 /stagesite